# wrong time conversion using to_timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a java application which use this method to write time into field (`time`) in DB:

```
DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jerusalem")).getMilis()
```

the field in the DB has a `bigint` type

I use this query to show the time:

```
select to_timestamp(time/1000)
from my_table
```

And it seems that there is a diff of 3 hours in the result.
The correct hour is 7:00, but is shows as 4:00

Comment: Well, an "epoch value" knows nothing about time zones. One of the reasons storing a timestamp as an "epoch value" is a bad idea to begin with. That column should be a `timestamp with time zone` not some bigint value

Answer (score 3):

you need to convert to the correct time zone:

```
select to_timestamp(time/1000) at time zone 'ist'
from my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `timezone` parameter to the time zone to which you want the timestamp formatted.